# save and load one hot encoding for ML

Tags: python, machine-learning, one-hot-encoding

I have been searching for two days now and at seems I cannot grasp the solution. For a machine learning regression model, I need a hot encoding of some columns. The training data and model fitting is happening on my local PC. After this the model will be uploaded to the server for predictions.

The problem is that new data was not part of initial encoding so I need to hot encode it in same way as learning data on my PC. I found out that I can save the encoder (sklearn.preprocessing -> OneHotEncoder).
But I cannot manage to get the data into the correct format.

To make it easier to understand here I just created a notebook with some very simple dummy data.

```
# Import pandas library 
import pandas as pd 
# initialize list of lists 
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]] 
# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age']) 
# print dataframe.
df
```

Output:

Name    Age

tom 10

nick    15

juli    14

---

```
# hot encoding
hot_Name = pd.get_dummies(df.Name)
X = pd.concat((df[['Age']], hot_Name), axis=1)
X
```

Output:

Age juli    nick    tom

10  0   0   1

15  0   1   0

14  1   0   0

---

```
# outside data
# initialize list of lists 
data_new = [['michael', 20], ['juli', 45]] 
# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df_new = pd.DataFrame(data_new, columns = ['Name', 'Age']) 
# print dataframe. 
df_new
```

Output:

Name    Age

michael 20

juli    45

Is it possible to encode "data_new" the same way as "data" and save the Encoder for latter use on live incoming data?

Expected hot encoding to be used in th Model for df_new:

Age juli    nick    tom

20  0   0   0

45  1   0   0

Comment: So what does it have to do with django?

Comment: yeh sorry, Im implementing it in that in that. But not direct connection. Will delete the tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, `pandas` does not expose a method to serialise encoding done with `get_dummies`. I'd use `OneHotEncoder` directly to encode the variables and then `joblib` to serialise it.

```
import joblib
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

col_names = ['name', 'age']
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]] 

enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='error')
enc.fit(data)
joblib.dump(enc, 'encoder.joblib')
```

Then on the server:

```
enc = joblib.load('encoder.joblib')
data_df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=col_names)
enc_df = pd.DataFrame(data=enc.transform(data).toarray(), columns=enc.get_feature_names(col_names), dtype=bool)
df = pd.concat([data_df, enc_df], axis=1)
```

Output for `df`:

```
|   | name | age | name_juli | name_nick | name_tom | age_10 | age_14 | age_15 |
|---|------|-----|-----------|-----------|----------|--------|--------|--------|
| 0 | tom  | 10  | False     | False     | True     | True   | False  | False  |
| 1 | nick | 15  | False     | True      | False    | False  | False  | True   |
| 2 | juli | 14  | True      | False     | False    | False  | True   | False  |
```

Comment: Thank this is very helpfull, but not quite the solution. In the "on the server" part you put in the initial information again into the encoding. When I try to get the information of "michael" of df_new there is an error "Found unknown categories ['michael'] in column 0 during transform". Also another problem is that OneHotEncoding encoded all the columns. The age should not be ancoded as this is a real comparable set of values and should stay in one column for ML.

Comment: @DimiDev I don't know what you're modelling so can't tell what makes sense to encode. In some circumstances one-hot encoding of age is a good move. As for the error when a new category appears on the prediction, it's on purpose. How your model should work with categories to which it was not exposed in the past? Handle the problem accordingly. You can also elect to ignore the error with `OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')`, if that's what you need.

Comment: Did some testing, and still have problems with "not encoding the Age". But yes handle_unknown helped alot. Will post the result.

Comment: If in the `data` you pass only names, with no, you won't get age encoding. I am sure it's obvious, so likely there's some complexity I am not getting. Mind you can pass any 2d array (optionally treat your 1d with `reshape`) that you need OHE (One-Hot Encoded) and then `concat` with the rest of the data.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Lukasz Tracewski:
As categorical_features does not work anymore. The dataframe had to be separated into two df's, one with data for encoding and another for not encoding and concatenated afterwards.

```
import joblib
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

col_names_encode = ['Name']

# learning data
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age']) 

# data from data lake
data_new = [['michael', 20], ['juli', 45]] 
df_new = pd.DataFrame(data_new, columns = ['Name', 'Age']) 

# get only data for encoding
df_encode = df.drop(columns=["Age"])

# one hot encoding
enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
enc.fit(df_encode)
df_encode = pd.DataFrame(data=enc.transform(df_encode).toarray(), columns=enc.get_feature_names(col_names_encode), dtype=bool)
# trasfer true and false to 1 and 0
df_encode = df_encode * 1

# concatenate data
df = pd.concat((df[['Age']], df_encode), axis=1)

#use the encoder to encode new incoming data
df_new_encode = df_new.drop(columns=["Age"])

df_new_encode = pd.DataFrame(data=enc.transform(df_new_encode).toarray(), columns=enc.get_feature_names(col_names_encode), dtype=bool)
df_new = pd.concat((df_new[['Age']], df_new_encode), axis=1)
df_new = df_new * 1

df_new.head()
```